# Squeeking noise issue with Asus laptop. Found working solution for Windows, now how to do this on Ubunutu?

Tags: sound, 14.04, asus, cpu, noise

My Asus laptop makes a high pitch squeeking noise/sound.

It turns out that is has something to do with the CPU and its power saving settings. I have my laptop on dual-boot with Windows 7 and Ubuntu 14.04 LTS.

For Windows 7 I found [this applicable and working solutions](http://asusnoise.blogspot.nl/); now how can I fix this irritating sound in Ubuntu?

Comment: Perhaps this can help http://askubuntu.com/a/285681/265974

Comment: I have the same problem with my Asus laptop. Installing TLP did not fix this problem for me

Comment: Not having actually heard the sound, my first guess would be fan noise. If this were the case I would replace the fan before it failed and reduced my CPU to slag...

Answer (score 0):

What you are hearing are probably the coils of the CPU power converter, when the CPU switches between powersaving modes, so in order to get rid of the sound you have to disable the powersaving modes, which will have a negative impact on power draw.

In order to do this, you have to add the kernel cmdline option `cpuidle_sysfs_switch` to your bootloader configuration. Then you can disable modes by writing a `1` to the `disable` files in `/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpuidle/stateX/`.

First change to root by running `sudo -i`, then disable states with, for example,  `echo 1 >/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpuidle/state3/disable`.

You'll have to try which powerstates you have to disable. Once you have figured it out, you can make the changes permanent by adding the command lines to `/etc/rc.local`, before the last line, which by default is `exit 0`.

The official documentation can be found [here](http://lxr.linux.no/linux+v3.14.4/Documentation/cpuidle/sysfs.txt).